# Amazon ELB + EC2 Header mismatch

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, http-headers, amazon-elb

Preamble:
I have an AWS Elastic Load Balancer in front of a Single Amazon EC2 instance.
I have 3 other EC2 instances sending requests via curl to the Load Balancer.
Direct requests to the EC2 ip has stable response times, and an acceptable speed.
Requests to the ELB has higher response times on average, with less than ideal speed.

My observations are nearly identical to this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=419138

```
"ELB's backend requests to the EC2 instance expect to be on HTTP 1.1 keep-alive connections. The instance/server needs to either support keep-alive connections OR explicitly return response headers to ELB that note the connection is closed.

Not returning that header and also not keeping alive the connection on the server results in ELB thinking the connection has been kept alive, waiting for ~30 seconds, and then retrying at that point with a new connection (hence the quick response times on the server, but slow perceived latency outside the ELB)."
```

My problem:
Dumping the response header from the ELB it still has the keep-alive header.
Dumping the response header directly from the EC2 instance, it has the `Connection: close`.

I am still experiencing the highly variable speeds/latencies that are mentioned in that above thread when going through the ELB instance, but as far as I can tell, I've explicitly sent `"Connection: close"` headers back from the EC2 instance to the ELB.

Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: *"Conenction"*?  At the risk of stating the obvious, if you dumped that header directly from the instance, you will want to check the spelling.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Just a typo in the SF question, fixed

Comment: It wouldn't be at all unheard-of for an http load balancer to rewrite the `Connection:` header in one or both directions; it's common for some load balancers to keep the client connection alive while closing the server connection.  I haven't had an opportunity to verify the behavior of ELB but I'll give it a shot, or someone else may come along with some test results.  Have you enabled logging on the ELB? There are timers in the logs.

Comment: My testing shows that ELB appears to be rewriting the `Connection:` header in both directions.  On Client → Server (request) it changes `keep-alive` → `close`; On Server → Client (response) it changes `close` → `keep-alive`... so what you are observing appears to be correct/normal behavior.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks. Glad I'm not just crazy.  Seeing as that can't be changed, I guess we'll just have to deal with it if we want to use AWS ELB.